# Spring Boot 2.0.0M2 Thymeleaf 3 failed to convert field

Tags: spring, jpa, thymeleaf

After upgrading to **spring-boot-2-m2** (thymeleaf 3) I am getting failed conversion errors for fields that correspond to JPA relationships.

`Failed to convert from type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn com.pps2....entities.FormType] to type [java.lang.String] for value 'com.pps2.....FormType@819841af'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Optional<?>] to type [java.lang.String]`

**JPA Entity**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_form_type")
private FormType type;

public FormType getType() {
    return type;
}
```

The code in the template is:

`<select th:field="*{type}" class="col-xs-12">`

Throws similar failed conversion error.

Of course when putting direct reference it works, but in that case it breaks a lot of templates in the project. And generates `name` as `type.id` and not `type`.

**Working example** 
`<select th:field="*{type.id}" class="col-xs-12">`

**Question** - Why did they change the API? And is there a way to resolve it without rechecking all the templates (e.g. writing converter?)?

Comment: Why do you say "Thymeleaf failed to convert" when it is Spring with the exception? And if that is the case what has JPA got to do with the problem of conversion ? aka debug where the problem is of those 3 bits of software

Comment: Thanks I'm very fresh to Spring environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write your own `Optional<T> to String` converter. I do not know why it was excluded from **Spring Boot 2 M2**

Converter code

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
final class OptionalToString implements Converter<Optional<?>, String> {

    public String convert(Optional<?> source) {
        return Objects.toString(source.get(),"");
    }
}
```

**Another option**

Is to specify directly the column (like `id`)

Working example  `<select th:field="*{type.id}" class="col-xs-12">`

Comment: I had to do the same thing in my case too. Also I think it would be helpful if you included your "Working example" from the question in the answer too as it is  also one of the possible fix for people migrating to spring 5 + thymeleaf